# Android 5.0: Volley cannot resolve hostname, same app on android 7.0 can

Tags: android, networking, android-volley

Android Studio 3.1.4: an app I've written works well with API 24 and newer.

But when starting to post (Volley)with API 21 device, I get the error

`UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host`

The host address is correct and can be called with the browser of the 5.0 device.

I'm using volley library 1.1.0.

Permissions are requested in the manifest as well as in program code to serve older and newer versions: Internet / Netword_State / Wifi_State.

Wifi connection, as well as GSM connection, is very good.

Any idea why it should work on API >23 and not with older ones?

Comment: Please post code with logcat so that i or some one else can help and also if you do not want to get down voted this question as soon as possible.

Comment: Found out myself: you have to use Volley 1.1.1, then it works.